# How to remove everything from HTML except special tag in java?

Tags: java, html, regex

I want to parse HTML String by extracting only `<form> ... </form>`. All other stuff don't needed and I can remove it.

Today I have some helpers to remove through `replaceAll` special tag content like:

```
    /** remove form */
    String newString  = string.replaceAll("(?s)<form.*?</form>", "");
```

> `(?s)<form.*?</form>`

removes `form` tags. But I need vice versa, remove everything except `form`.

How can I fix it?

See my [Gskinner](http://regexr.com?35h55) example

Comment: Generally, it's a good idea to parse html with dom parser.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes pages have errors like no close tag, in this case this approach is not good idea

Comment: In that case try: `String newString  = string.replaceAll(".*?(<form.*?</form>)", "$1");`

Comment: @PLB doesn't work, it still removes form content

Comment: Could add demo so we can play with? [Here's](http://ideone.com/) my fav tool.

Comment: see my post last row , I added link

Comment: http://ideone.com/XsxrTE Fixed regex little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Client {

    private static final String PATTERN = "<form>(.+?)</form>";
    private static final Pattern REGEX = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);

    private static final boolean ONLY_TAG = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "Hello <form><span><table>Hello Rais</table></span></form> end";
        System.out.println(getValues(text, ONLY_TAG));
        System.out.println(getValues(text, !ONLY_TAG));

    }

    private static String getValues(final String text, boolean flag) {
        final Matcher matcher = REGEX.matcher(text);
        String tagValues = null;
        if (flag) {
            if (matcher.find()) {
                tagValues = "<form>" + matcher.group(1) + "</form>";
            }

        } else {
            tagValues = text.replaceAll(PATTERN, "");
        }
        return tagValues;
    }
}
```

You will get below output

```
<form><span><table>Hello Rais</table></span></form>
Hello  end
```

Answer (score -1):

The below code will give you a direction in what you are looking for:

```
 String str = "<html><form>test form</form></html>";
 String newString  = str.replaceAll("[^<form</form>]+|((?s)<form.*?</form>)", "$1");  
 System.out.println(newString);
```

Comment: You should read about the [negated character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^...]`, they don't behave the way you think.